# Is it possible to exit span to target label after using ":focus" on the input element?

Tags: html, css

How would I target this label in css after the input is focused?

```
<div class="custom_floating">
    <span>
        <input type="text" id="firstname">
    </span>
    <label for="floatingFirstName">First Name</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not entirely clear to me. But, if you need to change the styles of the element after the element with *focus*, then use the pseudo-class `:focus-within` :

```css
.custom_floating > span:focus-within + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom_floating">
  <span>
    <input type="text" id="firstname">
  </span>
  <label for="floatingFirstName">First Name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you very much!